# JSON.parse() gives an error. Need to troubleshoot

Tags: javascript, json

I need to parse a string to a JSON object using JSON.parse() and got some error. The string is well formatted.

I tried other approaches and failed.

This is the string:

```
[
  {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "jafvert_march_samples",
  "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
  "features": [
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A1", "Descript": "upstream Sumbay Bridge" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -71.36309667, -16.06520167 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A2", "Descript": "under Bajo Grau Bridge" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -71.53931667, -16.39373 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A3", "Descript": "close to San Martin Bridge" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -71.54518, -16.40625333 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A4", "Descript": "under Tiabaya Bridge" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -71.59722833, -16.45542333 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A5", "Descript": "upstream Uchumayo Bridge" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -71.673785, -16.42648667 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A6", "Descript": "100 m downstream Sta. Rosa Bridge" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -71.69157667, -17.02936667 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A7", "Descript": "close to Freira Bridge, side Cocochacra town" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -71.77515167, -17.13146833 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A8", "Descript": "before Quilca bridge turned left, 500 m along left bank" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -72.405225, -16.69073667 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A9", "Descript": "Gravel road parallel to the river, Puchun town, turn left at church Sta  Rosa " }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -72.75407833, -16.61971667 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A10", "Descript": "directly under the Siguas Bridge" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -72.12923167, -16.34259833 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A11", "Descript": 'Pedregal town, Pond "Junta de Usuarios Pampa Baja", inflow to storage pond at flume' }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -72.19501, -16.387625 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A12", "Descript": 'Pedregal town, Pond "Junta de Usuarios Pampa Baja", exit well from storage pond' }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -72.19616667, -16.38854667 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A13", "Descript": "Punta Colorada Bridge, from top of the bridge, closer to right bank" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -72.45209833, -16.27445167 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A14", "Descript": "Aplao Bridge, at top left corner of the bridge (direction from Aplao village)" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -72.48210333, -16.077535 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A15", "Descript": "Acoy villadge, hanging bridge / hydrological tsunami  station" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -72.483685, -16.00815333 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A16", "Descript": "Under the bridge, North of Acoy, slightly North from the sampling point 15" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -72.476565, -16.00008167 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A17", "Descript": 'Under Oconia Bridge, next to red cabin "Ministry of Defense"' }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.117125, -16.42443 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A18", "Descript": "Under Vitor Bridge, in La Joya region" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -71.92866667, -16.46566167 ] } },
  ]
  }
]
```

using JSON.parse()

This is the error message:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2282
>       at JSON.parse
>       at eval:1:6
>       at eval
>       at o.

Comment: JSON strings must be double quoted. `'Pedregal town...` → `"Pedregal town...` and escape the double quotes within the string `"` → `\"`. Also, JSON doesn't support trailing commas so remove the comma after the last array item. For future reference, try using https://jsonlint.com/ first

Comment: Ctrl+F, and search for it (`'`) here and now. While that is valid for JavaScript source, it is not valid for JSON.

Comment: I'd guess you need to use double quotes and escape the double quotes in your `Descript` values

Comment: And remove the last comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the value of "Descript" is not within double quotes, but single which makes it invalid JSON. Also your double quotes inside should be escaped. I personally like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to validate my JSON. This is the valid JSON:

```
[
  {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "jafvert_march_samples",
  "crs": {
      "type": "name",
      "properties": {
          "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
  "features": [
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A1", "Descript": "upstream Sumbay Bridge" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -71.36309667, -16.06520167 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A2", "Descript": "under Bajo Grau Bridge" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -71.53931667, -16.39373 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A3", "Descript": "close to San Martin Bridge" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -71.54518, -16.40625333 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A4", "Descript": "under Tiabaya Bridge" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -71.59722833, -16.45542333 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A5", "Descript": "upstream Uchumayo Bridge" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -71.673785, -16.42648667 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A6", "Descript": "100 m downstream Sta. Rosa Bridge" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -71.69157667, -17.02936667 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A7", "Descript": "close to Freira Bridge, side Cocochacra town" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -71.77515167, -17.13146833 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A8", "Descript": "before Quilca bridge turned left, 500 m along left bank" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -72.405225, -16.69073667 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A9", "Descript": "Gravel road parallel to the river, Puchun town, turn left at church Sta  Rosa " }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -72.75407833, -16.61971667 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A10", "Descript": "directly under the Siguas Bridge" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -72.12923167, -16.34259833 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A11", "Descript": "Pedregal town, Pond \"Junta de Usuarios Pampa Baja\", inflow to storage pond at flume" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -72.19501, -16.387625 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A12", "Descript": "Pedregal town, Pond \"Junta de Usuarios Pampa Baja\", exit well from storage pond" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -72.19616667, -16.38854667 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A13", "Descript": "Punta Colorada Bridge, from top of the bridge, closer to right bank" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -72.45209833, -16.27445167 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A14", "Descript": "Aplao Bridge, at top left corner of the bridge (direction from Aplao village)" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -72.48210333, -16.077535 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A15", "Descript": "Acoy villadge, hanging bridge / hydrological tsunami  station" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -72.483685, -16.00815333 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A16", "Descript": "Under the bridge, North of Acoy, slightly North from the sampling point 15" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -72.476565, -16.00008167 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A17", "Descript": "Under Oconia Bridge, next to red cabin \"Ministry of Defense\"" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.117125, -16.42443 ] } },
  { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id": 0, "Name": "A18", "Descript": "Under Vitor Bridge, in La Joya region" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -71.92866667, -16.46566167 ] } }
  ]
  }
]
```